# How can I initialize a class without an package, autoloading

Tags: php, autoload, psr-0

```
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Test', __DIR__ . '/lib');
$loader->register();

$router = new Test\Router;
```

But what If I don't want to add the namespace Test when I initialize my classes, is that possible?

Like: $router = new Router;

...

```
<?php
namespace Test;

class Router
{
    public function __construct() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another use statement like you see at the top:

`use Test\Router;`

Now you can:

`$router = new Router();`

Comment: Or `use Test\Router as TestRouter; $router = new TestRouter;`. Well, thats not the best example to show, that a more descriptive classname may be useful sometimes :)

Comment: No problem - please mark it as the accepted answer if it solved your problem so others will know that a solution was found.